# Trace .exe and .dll code using .exe profiler when i run my .exe

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there any way to get code line by line using any Exe profiler when i run my Exe.

Problem scenario as follow.

```
I have Windows Exe with 30 supported .dll files.I want to trace code when i run this .exe.
I have already using ILSpy.exe  which decompile code.But I want decompile code at run time same as SQL Server Profiler.
```

Is there any way to decompile my .exe as sql server profiler.

Comment: [ANTS Performance Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/) can profile queries and code at the same time (i.e. "this code dispatched this query").